Are a fixed amount of pairs sufficient to output any permutation here?
Let $T$ be any finite set such that for any $2$ elements $a \in T$ and $b \in T$, either $a<b$ or $b>a$. Say we have some sort of a collection $C$ with a notion of order, such as a list, which contains all of the elements of $T$, and we are interested in what the permutation of the elements of $C$ is in which all of its elements are sorted. I was wondering whether the following statement is true: for any  $k\le |T|$, there exists a set  $X \subseteq \{(a,b) \in T \times T: a \neq b\}$ where $|X| = k$ such that if for any permutation of $C$ there exists some pairs of distinct elements of $C$ which number at most $k$, such that knowing for each of these pairs $(a,b)$ whether $a>b$ or $b<a$ allows us to prove $\pi$ is the sorted permutation of $C$'s elements, then we could deduce that $\pi$ is the sorted permutation of $C$'s elements looking solely at whether for each $(a,b) \in X$, whether $a<b$ or $b>a$.
I am also curious whether any set of $k$ elements $\{(a,b) \in T \times T: a \neq b\}$ has this property (which means $X$ isn't special or unique in having this property). The reason why I am asking this question is because I am trying to understand a certain combinatorial argument as to why $n \log n$ comparisons are necessary in the worst case to sort a list: the argument says that if a sorting algorithm performs at most $k$ comparisons, then there are at most $2^k$ permutations of its input it could output; so $k$ must be at least $\log_2 n!$ (where $n$ is the length of our input, which is $|T|$ in my above question) for us to be able to output all of the  $n!$ permutations of our input. However, this argument seems to assume that we have a fixed set of $k$ pairs ($X$ above in my example) which we are comparing- and it seems to me that if we look at comparisons in a different set of $k$ pairs, we may be able to output a permutation not accounted for by a fixed set of these $k$ pairs. My question basically clarifies that there isn't another permutation we could output which isn't accounted for by some fixed set of $k$ pairs by looking at another set of $k$ pairs.

I feel like the first part of your question is a bit confusing, at least to my understanding. Should $X$ not be a subset of $C\times C$? It's perfectly fine to think of this as an $n$-entry array containing the numbers $1$ through $n$. It works for arbitrary finite ordered sets stored in ordered data structures, but that setting is isomorphic to finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ stored in finite arrays, at least for swap/compare-sorting.
Anyways, to your actual question you should note first that there always is a set of $n-1$ comparisons that determines the permutation of your list $C$; simply compare the smallest to the second smallest etc. However you do not know what those comparisons should be, and a sorting algorithm has to, in particular, determine those comparisons. In the process it will also make some comparisons that are not strictly necessary.
The lower bound argument you refer to tries to capture that. Notice that it does not actually claim that an algorithm uses a fixed set of $k$ comparisons making a decision based on the outcome of those. It instead says that every time it makes some comparison, it doubles the amount of permutations it can distinguish since it branches in only two directions. That holds even if the algorithm is allowed to dynamically adapt the comparisons it makes (in fact that is necessary to obtain a good sorting algorithm). Thus if it always uses at most $k$ comparisons it can distinguish at most $2^k$ permutations of the input since the tree of all possible execution paths of such an algorithm is binary and has depth at bounded by $k$.

thanks 2 questions about your answer: 1. In my question I quantified any permutation after we already have the pairs to compare- so if we compare the first smallest to the second smallest, etc. this wouldn't be the same set of pairs for each permutation, right? So how is this a single set of pairs (in terms of the original positions of the elements in the (potentially unsorted) input) which works to determine the sorted permutation for any permutation? 2. Can you elaborate more on what the binary tree would look like when we don't have a fixed set of $k$ comparisons? Because (cont)

2 possibilities to me refer to 2 possibilities for a single comparison- the 2 results obtained by a single comparison. I don't see how we can vary as to which comparison we perform and have that branch  off into 2 possibilities
